# Display a graphic overlay without capturing it during screen capture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm working on an app that does full screen captures, but have a need to have a control view be visible at the same time. I'd like to be able to do the screen capture without capturing the view, however. I'm recording screen activity to a .mov file, not doing discrete screenshots.

I'm using AVCaptureScreenInput and successfully doing my screen captures. I realize this is an open-ended question (apologies!) but I'm not sure where to begin searching for the answer.

Is there a property of UIView's that can be applied?

Comment: That's actually the answer. Hide from view when you take the shot, err, I mean, hide the view when you take the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've been needing to look back over old questions and accept more. My verbiage of "screen capture" was inaccurate, I now realize. I'm recording screen activity to a .mov file, not doing discrete screen captures. Otherwise that's a good idea!